# Correaltion and regression analysis

Tags: statistics, regression, correlation, linear-regression, nonlinear-functions

How should I  analysis the correlation between four ordinal numbers (0,1,2,3) and various range of the continuous values? The scatter plot looks like a  4 parallel  horizontal dots .

Comment: Please show example data, and preferably code

Comment: I would like to upload the plot of data but I am not able because of low reputation, can I have your email?

Comment: Can you show the raw data table? That way someone else might be able to answer too.

Comment: data1(0.045812)
data2(.00
.00
.00
.00
.00
.00
.00
.00
.00
.00
.00
.00
.00
.00
1.00
.00
1.00
.00
.00
.00
.00
.00
1.00
.00
2.00
2.00
.00
1.00
.00
2.00
.00
.00
.00
.00
1.00
.00
.00
.00
1.00
.00
2.00
2.00
.00
.00
2.00
.00
1.00
1.00
2.00
2.00
2.00
1.00
2.00
2.00
.00
.00
.00
1.00
.00
1.00
2.00
.00
1.00
.00
1.00
.00
1.00
2.00
1.00
1.00
3.00
1.00
1.00
3.00
3.00
2.00
1.00
1.00
1.00
.00
2.00
1.00
.00
2.00
.00
.00
2.00
.00
.00
1.00
.00
2.00
.00
.00
.00
.00
1.00
2.00
2.00
2.00
.00
1.00
1.00
2.00
2.00

Answer (score 0):

You could run a Spearman rank correlation test.  Using R,

```
require(pspearman)
x <- c(rep("a", 5), rep("b", 5), rep("c", 5), rep("d", 5))
x <- factor(x, levels=c("a", "b", "c", "d"), ordered=T)
y <- 1:20

spearman.test(x, y)

    Spearman's rank correlation rho

data:  x and y
S = 40.6203, p-value = 6.566e-06
alternative hypothesis: true rho is not equal to 0
sample estimates:
      rho 
0.9694584 

Warning message:
In spearman.test(x, y) : Cannot compute exact p-values with ties
```

Non-significant correlation

```
set.seed(123)
y2 <- rnorm(20)
spearman.test(x, y2)

Spearman's rank correlation rho

data:  x and y2
S = 1144.329, p-value = 0.5558
alternative hypothesis: true rho is not equal to 0
sample estimates:
     rho 
0.139602 

Warning message:
In spearman.test(x, y2) : Cannot compute exact p-values with ties
```